# Problem in harmonic analysis

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, normed-spaces, harmonic-analysis

suppose $p$ be a fixed psitive real number and $f$ is an entire function with $$\lvert f(0) \rvert^p=\int_\mathbb{C}\ \lvert f(z)\exp(-\alpha\lvert z \rvert ^2) \rvert^p dA(z) $$   where $\alpha >0,$ $dA(z)=dxdy=\text{euclidean area measure}$ and $z=x+iy$. Does it follow that $f(z)$ is a constant function? If yes, how does one prove it?

Comment: What is $p$ in your question?

Comment: p is positive real number.

Comment: Is it fixed or do you assume equality for all such $p$?

Comment: this p is fixed positive real number.

Comment: You should definitely add this information to your question.

Comment: Wild guess: if $p$ is fixed, then for any $f$ there is some $\alpha$ s.t. the equality is true.

Answer (score 0):

You need
$$
|f(0)|^p=\int_\mathbb{C}\ | f(z)|^p\exp(-p\alpha\lvert z \rvert ^2)\, dA(z) =g(\alpha).
$$
Let $f$ be a polynomial (of even an $f$ with $|f(z)|\ll \exp(|z|^2)$), with $f(0)\ne 0$.
Then
$$
\lim_{a\to 0} g(\alpha)=\infty,
$$
while
$$
\lim_{a\to\infty} g(\alpha)=0.
$$
Hence, there is a $\alpha_0>0$, such that
$$
|f(0)|^p=\int_\mathbb{C}\ | f(z)|^p\exp(-p\alpha_0\lvert z \rvert ^2)\, dA(z) =g(\alpha_0).
$$

Comment: I need to know whether $f$ is constant or not. And here $\alpha$ is not a variable.